# Why isn't my cbuffer updating?

Tags: directx11, hlsl, c++

I am really frustrated because my cbufer isn't updating.
This is my VS:

```
cbuffer MatrixBuffer: register(b0)
{
float4x4 worldViewProj;

};

struct VertexIn
{
float4 Pos : POSITION;
float4 Color: COLOR;
};

struct PixelIn
{
float4 PosH : SV_POSITION;
float4 Color: COLOR;
};

PixelIn VS (VertexIn vin)
{
PixelIn vout;

vin.Pos.w = 1.0f;

vout.PosH = mul(vin.Pos, worldViewProj);

vout.Color = vin.Color;

return vout;
}

PixelIn VS1(VertexIn vin)
{
PixelIn vout;

vin.Pos.w = 1.0f;
vout.PosH = vin.Pos;

vout.Color = vin.Color;

return vout;
}
```

When using VS1 it draws correctly, but when using VS it doesn't draw anything?

Here is my CBUFFER update code

```
bool Game::UpdateShaders()
{
    HRESULT result;
    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedResource;
    MatrixBufferType* dataPtr;

    worldViewProjM = worldM * viewM * projM;
    worldViewProjM = XMMatrixTranspose(worldViewProjM);
    result = md3dDeviceContext->Map(mMatrixBuffer, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &mappedResource);
    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        MessageBoxW(mMainWnd, L"FAOE:", 0, 0);
        return false;
    }

    dataPtr = (MatrixBufferType*)mappedResource.pData;

    dataPtr->worldViewProj = worldViewProjM;

    md3dDeviceContext->Unmap(mMatrixBuffer, 0);

    int NBuffers = 0;

    md3dDeviceContext->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &mMatrixBuffer);
    //md3dDeviceContext->PSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &mMatrixBuffer);

    return true;
}
```

Here is my MATRIXBUFFERTYPE struct:

```
struct MatrixBufferType
{
        XMMATRIX worldViewProj;
};
```

This is called after I clear my depth stencil view and render target view.
Does somebody know why my CBUFFER isn't updating?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is no the matrix itself? The code generally looks correct for updating the CB.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn The matrix consists of a world matrix, which i specified as an identity matrix., a projection matrix which is just  XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(0.25 * 3.1415, mClientWidth / mClientHeight, 1.0f, 100.0f);
 XMStoreFloat4x4(&projM, proj); and a View matrix which is just  XMMATRIX V = XMMatrixLookAtLH(pos, target, up);

Comment: I see how you are computing it, but in the debugger you should inspect the values to make sure they are reasonable.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn How can I do that?

Comment: [Viewing Data in the Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esta7c62.aspx); [Overview of Visual Studio Graphics Diagnostics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873207.aspx)

Comment: You are mapping the buffer but you are not copping the data on it. Use memcpy to do it.

Comment: Have you tried setting your view matrix to the identity matrix too?

Answer (score 0):

you have to update your subresource (if i'm not mistaken):

```
md3dDeviceContext->UpdateSubresource(mMatrixBuffer, 0, NULL, &worldViewProjM, 0, 0);
```

Comment: I think you cant have a constant buffer who can map/unmap and UpdateSubresource. Because UpdateSubresource needs a Default usage buffer, and a Map.unmap needs a Dynamic buffer. I also tried just uodateSubresource, but that didn`t work either:(

Comment: You can either use ``UpdateSubresource`` or ``Map``/``Discard`` to update constants. See [Windows to Reality: Getting the Most out of Direct3D 10 Graphics in Your Games](http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/0/4/a04deeb2-d7e2-42a5-984a-9ea5c92bfeb2/Windows%20to%20Reality%20-%20Getting%20the%20Most%20out%20of%20Direct3D%2010%20Graphics%20in%20your%20Games.zip)

Answer (score -1):

Setting the cbuffer variable to matrix fixed it for me. Thanks all for youre help!